# Issues cancelling a swing worker

Tags: java, concurrency, swingworker

I am having some problems cancelling a swing worker. I am unsure after reading the documentation how to approach solving this

```
sw = new SwingWorker<Object, Void>()
{     
    Object o;
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception      
    {          
    //do some long running task via a method call
    } 
}
```

Then in my cancel button handler i just want to call `sw.cancel(true);`

This doesnt seem to be working though. According to the documentation the swing worker needs to no how to cancel iteslf. But, if the method to run the swing worker is only being calld once then how do i account for this with thread.sleep(which is what i've read is one way of fixing)

Thanks

Comment: What does the long running task do? It needs to be able to detect and react to thread interruptions, either by polling the thread interrupt status or by using non-blocking I/O.

Comment: just a series of method calls to invoke another project using reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing will actually monitor your work with a Future.  When you try to cancel the worker Swing will invoke `future.cancel(true)` (the true value will attempt to `interrupt()` the executing thread).

What this means is your work needs to respond to interruption.  If the long running computations don't respond to interruption you will have to put in some checkpoints and respond accordingly

```
protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception      
{          
   //do part 1 of long running task
   if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
     //clean up and return
   }
   //do part 2 of long running task
   if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
     //clean up and return
   }
   //etc..
}
```

Swing will simply notify the executing thread that it should cancel.  It is your responsibility to actually enforce cancellation.

Comment: so these checks coyuld actually go inside the method call that swing worker calls as they will be the ones run by the swing worker?

Comment: @Ricki That is exactly right.  The doInBackground is done on a separate thread known by swing worker so when Swing will invoke the cancel method Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() should return true.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good article here: http://blogs.oracle.com/swinger/entry/swingworker_stop_that_train

In brief, calling `cancel()` sets the thread's 'interrupted' flag. If you're doing I/O operations or calling `Thread.sleep()` then the flag gets checked in those and an `InterruptedException` will get thrown. If you do neither of those things, you can check it yourself using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and throw the exception.